# How to handle crmerrors in add of case through c# in dynamics crm?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I am adding case's fields data through c#.
but when I am adding particular contract look up field.It gives me below error for this field. otherwise for other look up field it works fine.

I also found that this is crmerror. but how to solve that I can't find.
below link displays that it is crm error.
http://www.mohamedibrahim.net/blog/2013/07/01/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-and-online-error-codes-full-list-api-web-service-sdk/

Code:

```
//data in postdata for add pass in service using ajax
var requestData = 
{
    "ModuleCode": "incident",
    "PostData": [{ "Key": "customerid", "Value": "a624c9dc-cc83-e611-80dc-fc15b428cc94", "Datatype": "lookup", "Entityname": "contact" }, { "Key": "title", "Value": "cq", "Datatype": "String" }, { "Key": "contractid", "Value": "d1f0f5cb-9c84-e611-80dc-fc15b428cc94", "Datatype": "Lookup", "Entityname": "contract" }, { "Key": "prioritycode", "Value": "3", "Datatype": "Picklist" }],
}
//below is the code that call addorupdate function from other function.
Entity moduledata = new Entity(modulename);
moduledata = addorupdate(moduledata, PostData, modulename);
newmoduledataid = _serviceProxy.Create(moduledata);
public Entity addorupdate(Entity moduledata, List<PostData> PostData, string modulename)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < PostData.Count(); i++)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        if (PostData[i].Datatype != null && PostData[i].Datatype != "")
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                if (PostData[i].Datatype.ToLower() == "picklist" || PostData[i].Datatype.ToLower() == "optionset" || PostData[i].Datatype.ToLower() == "dropDown")
                {
                    if (PostData[i].Value != null && PostData[i].Value != "")
                        moduledata[PostData[i].Key] = new OptionSetValue((Convert.ToInt32(PostData[i].Value)));                      
                }
                if (PostData[i].Datatype.ToLower() == "string" || PostData[i].Datatype.ToLower() == "memo" || PostData[i].Datatype.ToLower() == "multilinestext")
                {
                    if (PostData[i].Value != null && PostData[i].Value != "")
                        moduledata[PostData[i].Key] = PostData[i].Value;
                }

                else if (PostData[i].Datatype.ToLower() == "lookup")
                {
                    if ((PostData[i].Value != null && PostData[i].Value != "") && (PostData[i].Entityname != null && PostData[i].Entityname != ""))
                        moduledata[PostData[i].Key] = new EntityReference(PostData[i].Entityname, Guid.Parse(PostData[i].Value));   
                }
                //like this for all datatype
            }
        }
    }
    return moduledata;
}
```

ERROR:

> IncidentMissingContractDetail     -2147204095     The contract detail id is
>   missing.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, how are you assigning contract detail id? post some code.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM I edit my question with adding code.

Comment: Just debug and check the data